# Unmarshalling Error when I try to unmarshall the WebServiceResponse

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have a response from a 3rd party API, that give me an error for unmarshalling the xml response is similar to that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:webServiceResponse
    xmlns="http://ws.services.company.com"
    xmlns:ns2="http://rest.ws.services.company.com">
    <ns2:result>
        <success>true</success>
        <id>7054986</id>
    </ns2:result>
</ns2:webServiceResponse>
```

Normally I was testing my Java code with a xml response like that and I get success:

```
<webServiceResponse xmlns="http://ws.services.company.com">
  <result>
    <success>true</success>
    <id>1</id>
  </result>
</webServiceResponse>
```

In Java, I have been creating the respective XML Data class with the following xsd files.

`CompanyWS.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:jxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb" jxb:version="3.0" targetNamespace="http://ws.services.company.com" xmlns="http://ws.services.company.com" version="1.0" xmlns:ns2="http://ws.services.company.com" xmlns:ws="http://ws.services.company.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:include schemaLocation="CompanyWSTypes.xsd"/>

    <xsd:element name="someFunctionality">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexContent>
                <xsd:extension base="ns2:WebServiceRequest">
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="someEvent" type="ns2:InteractObject"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="recipientData" type="ns2:RecipientData"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:complexContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="someFunctionality2">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexContent>
                <xsd:extension base="ns2:WebServiceRequest">
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="customEvent" type="ns2:CustomEvent"/>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="recipientData" type="ns2:RecipientData"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:complexContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="webServiceResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="result" nillable="true" type="ns2:WebServiceResult"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>


</xsd:schema>
```

`CompanyWSTypes.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:jxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb" jxb:version="3.0" targetNamespace="http://ws.services.company.com" version="1.0" xmlns:ns2="http://ws.services.company.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsd:complexType name="InteractObject">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="folderName" type="ns2:minLengthString"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="objectName" type="ns2:minLengthString"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="RecipientData">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="recipient" type="ns2:Recipient"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="optionalData" nillable="true" type="ns2:OptionalData"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="Recipient">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="listName" type="ns2:InteractObject"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="recipientId" nillable="true" type="xsd:long"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="customerId" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="mobileNumber" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="emailAddress" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="permissionStatus" nillable="true" type="ns2:PermissionStatus"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="OptionalData">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="name" type="ns2:minLengthString"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="value" type="ns2:minLengthString"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:simpleType name="minLengthString">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="CampaignType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="TRANSACTIONAL"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="PROMOTIONAL"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="PermissionStatus">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="OPTIN"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="OPTOUT"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="NOT_SPECIFIED"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="PriorityLevel">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:int">
      <xsd:enumeration value="1"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="2"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="3"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:complexType name="WebServiceRequest">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="additionalData" nillable="true" type="xsd:anyType"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="transactionId" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="accountId" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="brandId" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="langLocale" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:attribute default="1" name="priorityLevel" type="ns2:PriorityLevel"/>
    <xsd:attribute default="TRANSACTIONAL" name="campaignType" type="ns2:CampaignType"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="CustomEvent">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="eventName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="eventId" nillable="true" type="xsd:long"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="eventStringDataMapping" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="eventDateDataMapping" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="eventNumberDataMapping" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="WebServiceResult">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="success" type="xsd:boolean"/>
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="id" nillable="true" type="xsd:long"/>
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="error" nillable="true" type="ns2:WebServiceError"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="WebServiceError">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="code" nillable="true" type="ns2:ErrorCode"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="message" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="ErrorCode">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELD"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="DATABASE_ERROR"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="SERVER_ERROR"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="LOGIN_ERROR"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

The error I get:

```
Unable to unmarshal to WebServiceResponse.
jakarta.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://rest.ws.services.company.com", local:"webServiceResponse"). Expected elements are <{http://ws.services.company.com}someFunctionality>,<{http://ws.services.company.com}someFunctionality2>,<{http://ws.services.company.com}webServiceResponse>
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:693) ~[task/:?]
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:230) ~[task/:?]
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:225) ~[task/:?]
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:92) ~[task/:?]
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1102) ~[task/:?]
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:527) ~[task/:?]
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:509) ~[task/:?]
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:137) ~[task/:?]
.
.
.
```

Can anyone help regarding this issue?

I think it cant associate the response namespace with ns2 which is associated with the uri start as `rest`. But I cant to do it on xsd files to associate with ns2 as it gives error all time.

Answer (score 0):

Your target namespace in XSD, and so in your Java generated code is `targetNamespace="http://ws.services.company.com"` but you receive the `webServiceResponse` in the `http://rest.ws.services.company.com` namespace.

That why the unmarshaller complains about not receiving one of the expected elements

Is your XSD created by yourself or send by someone else ? In any case to make it work, you should change the `targetNamespace` according to the expected one (with the `rest` prefix in it).